# оптимизация sql запроса к БД clickhouse с большим массивом в блоке IN

Tags: clickhouse

У меня есть система, работающая с большими объемами данных в clickhouse. При отфильтровывании значений для выборки данных через select я получаю к бэку запрос вида

```
SELECT
    param1,
    param2,
    ...,
    paramN
FROM
    table1 l ALL
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id1,
        id2
    FROM
        table2)
        USING (id1)
WHERE
    any_parameter IN (value1, value2, value3, ... valueN)
ORDER BY
    another_param1 DESC,
    id1
LIMIT 0,25
```

Так вот, внутри IN может быть огроменнейшее перечисление, начиная от 2500 значений. Плюс может быть присоединено ещё одно такое же через AND. Как можно блок IN оптимизировать? Пробовал со временными таблицами - не лучший вариант, быстро захламляется временными таблицами. Ещё подсказывают в интернете что надо разбить на подзапросы или использовать NOT IN.

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать через словари. Источником данных словаря может быть другая бд или веб сервис, данные словаря кешируются на некоторое время, в качестве значения может быть массив